# Acceptance testing of Spring MVC app

Tags: spring, testing, spring-mvc, acceptance-testing

Can you recommend some frameworks for acceptance testing of Spring MVC application?
Something like Rails "Capybara+Cucumber" would be ideal.
I have found only Selenium so far.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/606550/watir-vs-selenium-vs-sahi

Comment: Thanks! please post it as an answer so I can accept it=)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The testing framework doesn't actually depend on the server-side framework. So any one will do, regardless of whether you are using Spring MVC, JSF or whatever.

Selenium is, to my knowledge, the most popular and stable one, but [here's a comparison between a couple of options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606550/watir-vs-selenium-vs-sahi).

Also not that is more often called "functional" and "automated" testing